# NiFi ConvertRecord to transform nested json to csv

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have to convert nested json to csv:
Input Json:

```json
[
  {
    "phone": "657-676-6697",
    "city": "London",
    "rc": [],
    "rcName": "Andy"
  },
  {
    "phone": "",
    "city": "Paris",
    "rc": [
      {
        "email": null,
        "firstName": "Mary",
        "lastName": "Kim",
        "title": "Teacher"
      },
      {
        "email": "anna@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Frank",
        "title": "Student"
      }
    ],
    "rcName": ""
  },{
    "phone": "",
    "city": "",
    "rc": [ {
        "email": "pan@tt",
        "firstName": "Pan",
        "lastName": "Kurt",
        "title": "Teacher"
      }],
    "rcName": "Pan1"
  },
  {
    "phone": "",
    "city": "Oklahoma",
    "rc": [
      {
        "email": null,
        "firstName": "Pearl",
        "lastName": "Knox",
        "title": "Receptionist"
      },
      {
        "email": "Jim@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Jim",
        "lastName": "Hopkins",
        "title": "TA"
      }
    ],
    "rcName": ""
  }
]
```

Expected Output csv:

```
city,lastName,title
  London,
  Paris,Kim,Teacher
  Paris,Frank,Student
  ,Kurt,Teacher
  Oklahoma,Knox,Receptionist
  Oklahome,Hopkins,TA
```

Converting to csv for phone, city and rcName using ConvertRecord is working perfectly fine for me.
But it gives empty values for elements in nested json.
There were recommendations at link https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/2e265d53-43b9-42a4-94ad-6cbcc44cf395/y to transform the input JSON into "rows" using JoltTransformJSON. So, I am using following spec,

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "rc": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,city)": "[&1].city",
            "@(2,phone)": "[&1].phone",
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But, this JoltTransform is giving all the values in array and ConvertRecord is not able to parse it. Jolt Transform output:

```
[{
    "city": ["Paris", "", "Oklahoma"],
    "phone": ["", "", ""],
    "email": ["pan@tt", null],
    "firstName": ["Mary", "Pan", "Pearl"],
    "lastName": ["Kim", "Kurt", "Knox"],
    "title": ["Teacher", "Teacher", "Receptionist"]
}, {
    "city": ["Paris", "Oklahoma"],
    "phone": ["", ""],
    "email": ["anna@gmail.com", "Jim@gmail.com"],
    "firstName": ["Anna", "Jim"],
    "lastName": ["Frank", "Hopkins"],
    "title": ["Student", "TA"]
}]
```

[image: From Jolt transfering at https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception]

I have used ConvertRecord processor with following configuration:
RecordReader: JsonPathReader
RecordWriter: CSVRecordSetWriter

Comment: Please share output of jolt and specify what exact issue do you have. Using your jolt spec and your example i have got [ {
  "city" : "Paris",
  "email" : null,
  "firstName" : "Mary",
  "lastName" : "Kim",
  "title" : "Teacher"
}, {
  "city" : "Paris",
  "email" : "anna@gmail.com",
  "firstName" : "Anna",
  "lastName" : "Frank",
  "title" : "Student"
} ]
which looks ok to me as an input to ConvertRecord

Comment: @YuriR I have updated my question with JoltTransform output. For more data json is coming in array

Comment: this is not what i get on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/. Please try there. Probably nifi has a bug or you copied wrong Jolt Spec to your question :-)

Comment: @YuriR I am getting same output from both Nifi and link shared by you. Screenshot attached in question

Comment: can reproduce now. will update if i have progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used below JoltTransform spec which solved my issue

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "rc": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,city)": "[&3].[&1].city",
            "@(2,phone)": "[&3].[&1].phone",
            "*": "[&3].[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```